# Angularjs and IE10 no post data when saving resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm having trouble figuring out why my models are not getting saved in AngularJs when using IE10. It is working well in IE8, 9, Chrome and Firefox. The problem I am seeing using Fiddler is that no post data is getting sent with the request. The request is fired to the right place, but just post data at all. It is also a POST.

I have my code as follows:

```
app.factory('Things', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/v1/thing\\/', {}, {
              query: {method:'GET', params:{},isArray:true}});
        }); 


Things.save({
    'user': {
        'first_name':$("#student_first_name").val(),
        'last_name':$("#student_last_name").val()
    }, function(){
        //console.log("success");           
    }, function(){
        //console.log("Error adding a student.");
    }});
```

I am using Django on the backend with tastypie.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, but the brackets on `Things.save` don't seem to match up.

Comment: I fixed those up, my mistake while pasting the code. I am thinking it might be related to my browser, can't replicate it on other computers with IE10.

Comment: Sounds like it may also be a caching issue. Maybe it's using an older version of the JS.